# Qt Painter don't update

Tags: c++, qt

I need to paint simple rect but when I call update() function it doesn't do anything. Here is my code:

```
...//this is called when button is pressed, when application loads nothing should be drawn.

    draw = true;
    update();
}

void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e){
    QPainter painter(this);
    QLinearGradient lg(QPoint(20, 80), QPoint(215, 390));
    lg.setColorAt(0, Qt::white);
    lg.setColorAt(1, Qt::blue);
    QBrush brush(lg);
    painter.setPen(Qt::black);
    painter.setBrush(brush);
    if(draw == true){
    painter.drawRect(20, 80, 195, 300);
}
}
```

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in `MainWindow::paintEvent`? Is the code inside actually executed?

Comment: Is this a subclass of `QMainWindow`?  If it is, you shouldn't be trying to paint into it, you should instead use a separate widget and call `setCentralWidget`.

Comment: @Corijn yes, it is executed

Comment: @DanMilburn it is subclass of QMainWindow. I used this method in Qt4 and it worked well, I don't know how to imeplement your way.

Comment: Actually code works, only thing is, I can't paint anything above programatically created frame. When I moved my rect away from frame then I could see it. How can I draw rect inside new frame?

Comment: I'm guessing you have paintEvent in your header file as virtual? If so something else(centralWidget) is painting over it after your done. Try calling the base class paintEvent(QWidget::paintEvent(e);) at the very top of your paintEvent function before trying to paint the custom rectangle. Even if this works you should consider painting on a separate widget and set that as your centralWidget in QMainWindow

Comment: I don't understand you. Can you explain it in more details please.

Comment: your Mainwindow.h file do you have "virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e);" ??

replace first two lines of your current paintEvent to

void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e){
QWidget::paintEvent(e);
QPainter painter(this);

Comment: It's same. Mine paintEvent wasn't virtual but I changed it to virtual and it's same again, no change.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add

```
e->accept()
```

at the end of paintEvent function.